# Puppeteer - How to wait img after change innerHTML?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I would like to add an image before a screenshot with puppeteer.
The following code works but instead of waiting like this, I would like to wait until the img is here :

```
element.innerHTML = "<img id=\"logo_website\" src=\"http://random.com/logo.jpg\">";
await page.waitFor(2000)
```

I tried with the following "waitFor" but it doesn't work.

```
await page.waitFor("#logo_website")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`page.waitForResponse()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforresponseurlorpredicate-options) in this way:

```js
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function main() {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const [page] = await browser.pages();

    await page.goto('https://example.org/');

    await Promise.all([
      page.waitForResponse('https://www.iana.org/_img/2013.1/iana-logo-header.svg'),
      page.evaluate(() => {
        document.body.innerHTML = '<img id="logo_website" src="https://www.iana.org/_img/2013.1/iana-logo-header.svg">';
      }),
    ]);

    await page.screenshot({ path: 'scr.png' });

    await browser.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```